# Object.values - Remove unnessary properties or extract arrays from Datatables callback object

Tags: datatables, associative-array

I am generating from Datatables data object by `form_data = this.api().rows().data();` and i got

[form_data array of array from Datatables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCwN5.png) (image in link)

If i convert this by `console.log(Object.values(form_data));` i got this

[Object.values for form_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq8dB.png) (image in link)

Is some way how remove this other properties (functions etc) inside of object and will there only arrays and this should be convert by `Object.values()` or should somehow extract this arrays of `form_data` to new array variable where will only this arrays without other properties which are inside array ???

Comment: Why you should not upload [images of code, data, errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) when asking a question.

Comment: The DataTables [`toArray()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/toArray()) helper function may be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

As @andrewjames proposed... i need to add [.toArray()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/toArray()) inside my callback function in Datatables

```
            drawCallback: function() {

                form_data = this.api().rows().data().toArray();

            }
```

after this, Datatables generate me clean Object

see image [Object from Datatables only with arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAiCO.png)